# How to write following JPQL using Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Student -  Course  :   OneToMany

JPQL :

> select Student from Student student, Course course where
>   student.name=:STUDENTNAME and (course.courseName=:COURSENAME or
>   course.courseDuration=courseDuration)

Let us suppose one student might have 10 courses i want to retrieve only two records having Student - Courses(2).

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Student> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Student.class);
Root<Student> studentRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Student.class);
studentRoot.fetch("courses", JoinType.LEFT);
Predicate condition = criteriaBuilder.equal(studentRoot.get("studentName"), "someName");
//how to add course condition here.
criteriaQuery.where(condition);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear: the JPQL, the criteria, and your description do 3 different things. What exactly do you want to get? Also, if a course is followed by several students, then you have a ManyToMany, not a OneToMany.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent of JPA QL “JOIN FETCH” in Criteria API.

JOIN FETCH uses EAGER fetch irrespective of the fetch type specified in the model annotation.

If you are using criteria api, you can call the getter method of child in the dao,so that it gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope your Student entity has relation with Course mapping with property name course in student entity.

Here is Criteria Query

```
        Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Student.class);
        criteria.createAlias("course", "course");
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("name", STUDENTNAME));        
        Criterion courseNameCrit = Restrictions.eq("course.courseName", courseName);
        Criterion courseDurationCrit = Restrictions.eq("course.courseDuration", courseDuration);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction().add(courseNameCrit).add(courseDurationCrit));    
        List<Student> studentList = criteria.list();
```

Comment: @Thanks Rahul you might be correct but i'm using JPA Criteria.